# Microsoft Graph API authentication without the CLI

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-cli

From an environment where the [Azure cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) is and cannot be installed, how can I get an Auth token from a Service Principal? So I can run queries like:

```
curl -X -H 'Authorization: Bearer <auth-token>' \
    https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups
```

With the CLI this is fairly simple, I have a `tenant_id`, an `azure_client_id` and an `azure_client_secret`:

```
az login --service-principal -u <az_client_id> -p <az_client_secret> --tenant <tenant_id>
```

and then run for example:

```
az rest --method get --url https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups
```

### -- attempt 1

I do get an access token with request:

```
curl -X GET \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<azure-client-id>&resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d&client_secret=<azure-client-secret>' \
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
```

but is is apperantly not valid for the Microsoft graph API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me from Windows Command Prompt:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Result:

```
{
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "expires_in":3599,
  "ext_expires_in":3599,
  "access_token":"eyJ0...LUEQ"
}
```

You are missing `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, request URL should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token` and method should be `POST`.

I used double quotes instead of single quote for header and body parameters.

Resources:

[Get access without user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#token-request)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *@user2250152*, you are using wrong **resource** value to generate access token.

You can just change the value of `resource` parameter to **https://graph.microsoft.com** while generating access token like below:

```
curl -X GET \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<azure-client-id>&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&client_secret=<azure-client-secret>' \
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
```

When I ran the same in Postman, I got **access token** with Microsoft Graph as `resource` like below:

[image]

Now, use below **curl command** to run Graph query by including above access token like this:

```
curl -X -H 'Authorization: Bearer <auth-token>' \
    https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups
```

When I ran same query in Postman, I got groups successfully like below:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups
Authorization: Bearer <auth-token>
```

**Response:**

[image]